# How many devices can I register with my iOS Developer Program Account?

Tags: ios, apple-developer

I have my 99$ subscription in apple developers portal my doubt is that for how many different devices i can test my application, is there any limitations say you can test in 10 different devices?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can test with up to **100 devices per year**.
This is to prevent developers from selling their apps outside the app store by using the developer certificate and registering an endless number of devices.

Even if you remove a device from the list, it will *still* count towards your 100 devices per year limit.

Comment: Hi DarkDust,If i use personal account for iOs development,

Comment: Hi DarkDust,  Please clarify me ,If i use personal account for iOS development,is the same? can  i register 100 devices with personal account??Thanks in advance..

Comment: AFAIK this is the same, yes.

Comment: i have registered 50 device currently now if i remove this 50 device first, then i can add other new 100 devices?

Comment: Is there any way to exceed this limit? There are a lot of very big companies. How do they solve this issue? Do they only test with just 100 devices?

Comment: @Akif: They're probably using [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/), which is actually a more convenient way to distribute test builds and currently has a limit of 10,000 users.

Answer (score 5):

You can use up to 100 devices per year.

Per [Apple Developer Account Management](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/) :

> You are allowed to register up to 100 iOS devices for testing and Ad Hoc distribution per membership year. Please Note: Although you may remove a device from your account, it will continue to count against your 100 device limit.

Comment: i have registered 50 device currently now if i remove this 50 device first, then i can add other new 100 devices?

Comment: From this: https://developer.apple.com/support/account/ it seems like you will only be able to add 50 more. However, that article also tells us that you can 'wipe the slate clean' once a year.

Comment: @SatishMavani I've updated my link, thanks to PixelCloudSt. You can remove a device from the list but it still continues to count against your yearly 100 devices limit. You only have the option to permanently have them removed once a year. So you really only can add 100 devices per year, there's no way to "cheat" that system.

Answer (score 1):

100 Devices per type per year
[Distribution Section of Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/whats-included/)

[image]